# refreshing javascript calculated sum total on new checkbox use without input fields

Tags: javascript, html-table

With help I've gotten this script to change the class of the function to include countable but need to get the total calculation to update the sum of all fields shown when that change takes place.

The scripts are split with the top one set to calculate the total of all countable class fields and the second script section set to show the line items and add the countable class.

```
<script>
var totals=[0,0,0];
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

    $dataRows.each(function() {
        $(this).find('.countable').each(function(i){        
            totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
        });
    });
    $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
        $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
    });

});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

    var $trElement = $('.' + val);
    var $tdPriceElement = $trElement.find('td.price');

    $trElement.toggle(isChecked);
    $tdPriceElement.toggleClass('countable', isChecked);
  });
});
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

These checkboxes allow display of the line items when selected.

```
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="42"/> example<br/>
<input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="43"/> example<br/>

<table id="sum_table">
<tr class="42" style="display:none">
  <td>example</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="price">7800</td>
</tr>
<tr class="43" style="display:none">
  <td>First Area</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="price">6900</td>
</tr>
<tr class="totalColumn">
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="totalCol"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @StackSlave Yeah very basic level of javascript for me here so its rough. What Im trying to do is get the total field to update whenever a checkbox is selected/deselected.

Comment: Unless you're doing some kind of animation *(and that's debatable with CSS these days)* you don't need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load jQuery before you can use it, so move:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

above the other 2 scripts. Then, replace your first script with this:

```
function showTotal(){
    //grab the .countable elements from the #sum_table
    var $countables =$("#sum_table .countable");

    //loop through and add up the total from their texts
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $countables.length; i++){
        total += Number($countables.eq(i).text());
    }

    //put the total in the .totalCol element
    $("#sum_table td.totalCol").html(total);
}
```

and call this function at the end of your onchange function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

    var $trElement = $('.' + val);
    var $tdPriceElement = $trElement.find('td.price');

    $trElement.toggle(isChecked);
    $tdPriceElement.toggleClass('countable', isChecked);

    //CALL IT HERE:
    showTotal();
  });
});
```

Comment: That solved all the issues I had with it. Thanks very much @Aaron Plocharczyk